# Array and List Error converting a code in c++ to python

Tags: python, c++, arrays, list

I am trying to convert a code in c++ to python and it seems to me that tho there are similarities of the code. There are also some huge differences like syntax and loops and condition implementation. Below is the code that I am working on.

```
process_queue = []
process_arrival = []
process_burst = []
process_holder = []
completion = []
waiting = []
turnaround = []
count = 0
time = 0
smallest = 0
i = 0
x = 0
end = 0
tt = 0
avg = 0
base = 0

n = int(input('Enter the total no of processes: '))
for i in range(n):

    process_queue.append([])
    process_arrival.append([])
    process_burst.append([])
    process_holder.append([])


    process_queue[i].append(input('Enter name: '))
    process_arrival[i].append(int(input('Enter arrival: ')))
    process_burst[i].append(int(input('Enter burst: ')))
    process_holder[i] =  process_burst[i]

    process_burst[i-0] = 9999

    for time in range(n):
        if count != n:
            smallest = 9
            for i in range(n):
                arr_val = ''.join(map(str,process_arrival[n]))
                int_arr_val = int(arr_val)
                burst_val = ''.join(map(str,process_burst[n]))
                int_burst_val = int(burst_val)
                burst_val_min = ''.join(map(str,process_burst[smallest]))
                int_burst_val_min = int(burst_val_min)
        
                if((int_proc_val <= time) and (int_burst_val < int_burst_val_min) and (int_burst_val > 0)):
                    smallest = i
            process_burst[smallest] - 1

            if process_burst[smallest] == 0:
                count += 1
                end = time + 1
                completion[smallest] = end
                waiting[smallest] = end - process_arrival[smallest] - process_holder[smallest]
                turnaround[smallest] = end - process_arrival[smallest]
```

**Here is the code in c++**

```c++
int a[10],b[10],x[10];
    int waiting[10],turnaround[10],completion[10];
    int i,j,smallest,count=0,time,n;
    double avg=0,tt=0,end;

    cout<<"\nEnter the number of Processes: ";  //input
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter arrival time of process: ";  //input
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter burst time of process: ";  //input
        cin>>b[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        x[i]=b[i];

    b[9]=9999;
    for(time=0; count!=n; time++)
    {
        smallest=9;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<=time && b[i]<b[smallest] && b[i]>0 )
                smallest=i;
        }
        b[smallest]--;

        if(b[smallest]==0)
        {
            count++;
            end=time+1;
            completion[smallest] = end;
            waiting[smallest] = end - a[smallest] - x[smallest];
            turnaround[smallest] = end - a[smallest];
        }
    }
```

Error that I encountered is

> IndexError: list index out of range

I am doing the conversion wrong?

Comment: "*I am receiving a bunch of errors*" Please include them in your question.

Comment: c++ to python or python to c++ ?!? Title says python to c++, question says c++ to python.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. English is not my 1st language. Ill edit the contents. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Yeah I thought it would work if I do it that way. @SergeBallesta

Comment: If you want a quick and dirty way, just use lists initialized to a given size. A general `for` loop from C can always be written as `initialization_part   while True:    if condition: break   instruction block  increments_part`. It leads to non Pythonic code. The alternative is to extract the specifications and code them from scratch. Of course there are plenty of use cases where the translation is simpler, but this loop `for(time=0; count!=n; time++)` will not be easy to translate into a Python `for var in smth:` loop...

Comment: @Key2020 Attempting to do line-by-line translations from Python to C++ is going to fail somewhere if you do not know both Python and C++ very well.  The way you actually "translate" is to figure out what the Python code is doing, and then once you figure it out, throw the Python code away and implement the program in C++.  Trying to emulate Python in C++ will just make your C++ code buggy, error-prone, or look weird to another C++ programmer.